# Schedule Task to reboot device but with warning

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, warnings, reboot

I have written a script to create a task in the task scheduler to reboot the device.
It is creating a task and working perfectly, but unfortunately, it is rebooting the device without working at all. Is there a way of warning people that the device is going to be rebooted or also an option to delay reboot? I could not find any method to add
Here is my script:

```
$action=New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "%SystemRoot%\system32\shutdown.exe"
$trigger=New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -DaysOfWeek Sunday -At 3am
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "Rebooting" -Description "Weekly rebooting"
```

Thank you very much in advace.

Comment: Add a time delay to your shutdown /r /t 5000

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using scheduled task to call the shutdown, why not use it to call a bat script at 3am on Sunday

```
@echo off
echo Your PC will reboot in 30 seconds! Press CTRL+C to abort.
ping -n 11 127.0.0.1 > nul
shutdown /r
```

the ping is a way to wait for 10 seconds, there are other ways to wait in a bat script.
change the " 11 " in the ping command to chang the amount of time it waits

if your users will get get scared of a black box you can use powershell to make it pretty and call a dialogue box with the same

use this for a pretty box

```
$pop = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$rebootWaitTime = 7200
if(6 -e $pop.Popup('yourmessagehere',0,'yourmessagehere',4)){
    shutdown /a
}else{
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $rebootWaitTime
    shutdown /r /f
}
```